# What is Clojure CLI tools "edn string" as arg?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to pass ClojureScript compile options, specifically `:asset-path`.

`clj --main cljs.main --help` says I should pass it on the command line as "an edn string".

What exactly is an edn string in this context?
(i.e. i'm failing to successfully guess what exactly I should enter in the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this works:

`--compile-opts "{:asset-path \"/js/compiled/out\"}"`

Comment: Even better:  `--compile-opts '{:asset-path "/js/compiled/out"}'`

Comment: To add to this: an edn string is a subset of the Clojure programming language and is used to describe data. It has some similarity to json in purpose, but has some important differences. You can use edn to define maps, lists, vectors, strings, keys, numbers and nest them. The specific answer to the arguments on the command line has a Clojure map with a single key, `:asset-path`, with the value "/js/compiled/out". This should help if you encounter more of these. Remember it could also be a vector or list and nested depending on what the CL argument accepts.